# Jenkins: The Error Message in Failed TestNG test is not formatted

Tags: java, jenkins, testng

In order to insert some message into HTML Report in testNG I've written following:

```
Assert.fail("<br><br><b>STACKTRACE:</b></b><br>"+ "\n\nSTACKTRACE:\n\n" + "&lt;BR&gt;&lt;BR&gt;STACKTRACE&lt;BR&gt;&lt;BR&gt;" + errorData.toString());
```

It's represented well in HTML Report. But in Jenkins when I go to "Test Result" link and click on some failed test in "All Failed Tests" section is shows Error Message in one line ignorring all tags < BR > and "backslash n" like following:

Error Message

**STACKTRACE:**
  STACKTRACE:  <pre><BR>STACKTRACE<pre><BR>expected: but was:expected: but was:expected: but was:TimeoutException: [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@c4afc4

Comment: Why are you using `&lt;BR&gt;` if you don't want it to appear in the generated text?

Comment: I just wanted to try all possible method to format the text. None of them make impact on formatting.

Answer (score -3):

< br > and any html tag not work.
However you can insert new line.

XML parsers converting the line breaks to single spaces in attribute values.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256097(v=vs.110).aspx

But & # 13; really work. Not forgot delete space.